# Pytorch Occured Error After Train Phase in First Epoch

Tags: python

I am beginner DL on pytorch.

classification that I made flow is as follows.

1. make custom dataset / dataloader

- dataset is imbalanced. so I use **Concatdataset** on train dataset for augmentation.
  (i also tried not using Concandataset. But it also error.)
- batch size is  2
- label is 0 or 1 ( binary)

2. load transfer model
3. train I referenced this code:  https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html

Problem is  **After first epoch** or **train phase in first epoch** and then, occurred 
**"RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered error"**  in  **running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0) step**. so I **printed forward steps**(before calculating running loss) outputs and prediction in each phase.

like that,

[image]

So I saw the results (examples).

**first epoch [train]**

[image]

**first epoch [valid]**

[image]

**second epoch[train] - error!!**

[image]

I wondering first train phase in the first epoch is run that contains calculating running loss. but it has not occurred error. 
is there a way to solve this?